# Data extract to SFTP subfolder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp, data-extract, sftp

I'm trying to export a file to an external SFTP but there is no parameter to select a subfolder on the SFTP. 
there is no options either in the file location or in the data extract activity.
it seems this option only exist for SFMC FTP, not for external SFTP.

is there any other way to select a subfolder instead of exporting my file directly to the SFTP root ?

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to SFSE!

I am afraid you are overthinking it. To set it to a subfolder, you need to create a file location specific to it.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to File Locations in Admin tab
2. Click on Create
3. add in name/externalkey/description
4. Select 'External FTP Site' (or SFTP, etc) from 'Location Type'
5. In Url you put the FULL Url, including subdirectories.  E.g. not just `ftp.exacttarget.com` but `ftp.exacttarget.com/import/mySubDirectory`
6. Add in user/pass for your FTP
7. Save

You can then use this file location to interact directly with a subfolder instead of only interacting with the root.

Comment: thank you its working ! in fact I tried it with filezilla and it didn't work so I though it wouldn't work either in SFMC...but it is working.